# How to find out a computer activities on domain controller by powershell

Tags: powershell

I can use "-properties lastlogontimestamp" to get information about last logon.

Is there a way that I can have a list of activities for a domain pc from AD by Powershell. lets say a list of time stamps that this PC logged on to domain?

Comment: `lastLogonTimestamp` for a computer account means the last time the _computer_ logged onto a domain controller. It has nothing to do with _users_ that log onto a computer.

Comment: @bill_stewart I am looking for the history of a PC that connects to the domain controller. not asking for user activities.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer by obtaining that information?

Comment: we have over 1K of records in AD as client PC and I dont know which one exists which one does not. by looking into the history that PCs contact DC with, I can tell if they are existing client PC or not.

Comment: You don't need a history of logons from a computer account to a domain controller to determine if a computer account is stale; the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute of the computer object works just fine for that.